# The designer cannot be shown because the document for it was never loaded - Visual Studio 2019

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm using **Visual Studio 2019** and I'm seeing the error shown in the screenshot below, when I double click on a form to view its design.
[image: Viual Studio 2019 Screenshot]

> The designer cannot be shown because the document for it was never loaded.

All the other forms open up just fine. I tried to create another form to clone the error form and just rename it and delete the error form and it works.

However, when I close the project and open it again, the error happens again. I have no idea of what's wrong. I tried cleaning the solution and rebuilding it as suggested by someone having the same problem but to no avail. Can anybody help me? Thank you.

Comment: Here's a tip: when you take a screenshot, keep it to what's relevant. That way, it won't be basically unreadable when it's down-sized to fit in the question.

Comment: For the record, that's a user control, not a form. Doesn't really matter for this question but it's not an insignificant detail.

Comment: What is under that node in the Solution Explorer if you expand it?

Comment: You might consider creating a new project and migrating your existing forms, controls, and code to the new project. This could help identify whether the issue is specific to your project or if it's related to the Visual Studio installation.

Comment: Usually when the designer or vs in general acts weird, delete bin, obj, packages, .vs folder and any .user files.